# maven release:prepare skips test-jar

Tags: maven, junit, release, maven-jar-plugin

I`m using maven ver. 3 with following plugin to generate separated *.jar file with tests.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>core-tests</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and my release plugin configuration looks following:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-8</version>
    <configuration>
        <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
        <preparationGoals>clean install</preparationGoals>
        <generateReleasePoms>false</generateReleasePoms>
        <scmCommentPrefix>
            release plugin -
        </scmCommentPrefix>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Generating test classes in separated jar works fine until I use:

```
maven clean deploy
```

When I`m doing release my test-jar is not created:

```
-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform
```

Release output:

```
...
[INFO] [INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] [INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] [INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] [INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] [INFO] [jar:jar {execution: default-jar}]
[INFO] [INFO] Building jar: /home/tomcat/hudson_home/jobs/project-core/workspace/target/core-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] [INFO] [jar:test-jar {execution: core-tests}]
[INFO] [INFO] Skipping packaging of the test-jar
...
```

I alos tried to use **DskipTests** but also without success

```
-Dresume=false -Darguments="-DskipTests" release:prepare release:perform -Prelease
```

or

```
-Dresume=false -Darguments="-Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true" release:prepare release:perform -Prelease
```

**How can I generate my test-jar during release?** Why it is skipped?

**EDIT**

I found that this problem occures only when I have active **release** profile. I can`t find this profile in any parent pom. Where it comes from? From maven-release-plugin definitions?

**RESOLVED**

I found profile **release** on hudsons *.m2/settings.xml*:

```
<profile>
    <id>release</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <username>*****</username>
        <password>*****</password>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

I just needed to remove *maven.test.skip* and everything works fine now.

Comment: This bug (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAR-138) details that jar:test-jar is skipped when `maven.test.skip=true`. Are you setting this property somewhere at all? Is there configuration from a parent pom that is being inherited maybe?

Comment: You are right. maven.test.skip was in settings.xml profile. Thanks for a good hint!